# docker group missing and docker refuses to be uninstalled

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, docker

this is a bit of a strange one.  I normally install docker using the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ but this time I got the 18.04 server install to do it.  I then went to let a suer use docker

sudo gpasswd -a ben docker
and got
  gpasswd: group 'docker' does not exist in /etc/group

So I thought it better to install it the way that has worked before, but when I removed docker

sudo apt purge docker

It was still installed, typing **docker** gives.

```
Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Options:
      --config string      Location of client config files (default "/home/ben/snap/docker/423/.docker")
  -D, --debug              Enable debug mode
  -H, --host list          Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -l, --log-level string   Set the logging level ("debug"|"info"|"warn"|"error"|"fatal") (default "info")
      --tls                Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
      --tlscacert string   Trust certs signed only by this CA (default "/home/ben/snap/docker
...
```

Don't want to install it the normal way I do when it just will not to die ;-). What is going on?

Comment: Logout and login again

Comment: Does not make any difference.  docker still there and if I reinstall docker and log out/in group is also not there.

Comment: run `newgrp docker` and if that fails reboot the system (if that's an option)

Comment: got 'newgrp: group 'docker' does not exist'.  But what I want to do is uninstall docker.

Comment: run `sudo dpkg -l | grep -i docker` and post the results

Comment: Was a VM so rebuilt it without docker.  Sorry ;-)